# How to append elements without overwriting in struct in c

Tags: c, struct, structure

I'm trying to call `rrandom` to choose one random id and name and put it in `buff struct`, and second time calling `rrandom` to choose new random value and putting it also in `buff struct` as a second item.

How can assign the second value to `buff` struct without deleting the first item ?

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <string.h>  
#define size 4

typedef struct Org                  
{
   int  id[4]; 
   char name[4][7];  
}org;

void rrandom(org select[size], ???){
int i,j,r=0;
for (i=0; i<1;i++){
   r = (rand() % (4 - 0)) + 0;
  for( j=0;j<4;j++){ 
    buf[i].id[j]= select[r].id[j] ;
    strcpy(buf[i].name[j], select[r].name[j]);

  }}
for ( int i=0; i<2 ;i++){

   for(int j=0;j<4;j++){ 
   printf("bname %s  bid = %d \n", buf[i].name[j], buf[i].id[j]);

 }}
}
void main(  )
{
int i,j;

org select[size]; 
org buf[2];

sprintf(select[0].name[0],"1ello1");
sprintf(select[0].name[1],"1ello2");
sprintf(select[0].name[2],"1ello3");
sprintf(select[0].name[3],"1ello4");
sprintf(select[1].name[0],"2ello1");
sprintf(select[1].name[1],"2ello2");
sprintf(select[1].name[2],"2ello3");
sprintf(select[1].name[3],"2ello4");
sprintf(select[2].name[0],"3ello1");
sprintf(select[2].name[1],"3ello2");
sprintf(select[2].name[2],"3ello3");
sprintf(select[2].name[3],"3ello4");
sprintf(select[3].name[0],"4ello1");
sprintf(select[3].name[1],"4ello2");
sprintf(select[3].name[2],"4ello3");
sprintf(select[3].name[3],"4ello4");
sprintf(select[4].name[0],"5ello1");
sprintf(select[4].name[1],"5ello2");
sprintf(select[4].name[2],"5ello3");
sprintf(select[4].name[3],"5ello4");
printf(" Initial id :\n");
for(i=0;i<4 ;i++)                         
{
    for(j=0;j< 4;j++)                       
    { 
         select[i].id[j]= j;        
}    }
rrandom(select,???);
rrandom(select,???);
for ( int i=0; i<2 ;i++){   
   for(int j=0;j<4;j++){ 
   printf("from main bname %s  bid = %d ", buf[i].name[j], 
    buf[i].id[j]);}
    printf("\n\n");
 } 
}
```

Comment: in `rrandom`, your loop `for (i=0; i<1;i++)` runs only on the first element. I think the indexes in the loop are messed up according what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the address of the resulting struct in `rrandom`:

```
void rrandom(org select[size], struct buff &bf){
  int j,r=0;
  r = (rand() % (4 - 0)) + 0;
  for( j=0;j<4;j++){ 
    bf->bid[j]= select[r].id[j] ;
    strcpy(bf->bname[j], select[r].name[j]);
  }
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++){ 
    printf("bname %s  bid = %d \n", bf->bname[j], bf->bid[j]);
  }
}
```

You can then use it in your main by replacing your `rresult` calls with:

```
rrandom(select, buf);
rrandom(select, buf + 1);
```